# Power BI Embed Hide tab page

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a embed Power Bi on my Aspnet app, I use the JavaScript Api to embed the Power Bi to my view.
In my Power Bi I have 4 reports. I need apply a rule to show for some users all 4 reports, and the others show only 1 or 2.

**The question is**, is there any way to hide the tab so the user can't click? I tried some ways, looking at the Microsoft documentation, but without success.

[powerbi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyGFN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can hide the tab in your embedded report by updating the setting and using `navContentPaneEnabled`. Please find the below code snippet:

1. Create new settings:

```js
const newSettings = {
    navContentPaneEnabled: false
};
```

2. Update new Settings:

```js
await report.updateSettings(newSettings);
```

Please find the reference here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-to-Hide-Power-BI-iFrame-Embedded-Report-Tabs/m-p/121541

Comment: navContentPaneEnabled hides all tabs, I need to hide only specific tabs